# Java Splitting a string within an array

Tags: java

I have a string array with username;password format such as

```
login[] = { "jake;pass", "oliver;king" } etc...
```

I then have a for statement to set the password depending on the username

```
for(int k = 0; k < login.length; k++){
    if(login[k].??? == username){
        password = ???
    }
```

How can I use substring or split to verify the username before the ";" as well as the password after the ";" ? I want to set password = everything after the ; and login[k].substring/split to everything before the ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to condense too much. It'll end up working against you.

Something like this should work:

```
for (int k = 0; k < login.length; k++) {
    String[] split = login[k].split(";");
    String user = split[0];
    String pass = split[1];

    if (user.equals(username)) { //make sure to  use equals() for Objects
        password = pass;
    }
}
```

I really hope you're not actually storing plaintext passwords for anything that needs to be secure, though.

Comment: Thank you very much, and no they are just simulated user:pass they aren't real :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it inline.
Maybe some stuff like this:

```
for(int k = 0; k < login.length; k++){
    String[] s = login[k].split(";");
    if(s[0].equals(username)){
        password = s[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: `s[1] = ???` should be `password = s[1]`. I also don't see why you need to set `login[k]` to the value you just retrieved from it...

Comment: true, I misunderstood the question. Thought to rewrite password in the login array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method split from String, like this:

```
String[] parts = login[k].split(";");
```